# Scraping subscriber count from YouTube link in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is a total beginner question so please be gentle!

I am trying to output the number of subscribers to a YouTube channel from a list of links to videos. [the link is on the left and I would like the subscriber count in the column on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUIAY.png) I've tried using a few solutions that I found on here but I couldn't get any to work!

Comment: How many such URLs do you have?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: keep in mind that not every channel has its subscriber count public, what you would do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the video URLs in the column "A" of the Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the video URLs and retrieve the values of subscriberCount.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I think that the following flow is required to be used.

1. Retrieve the video URLs from Spreadsheet.
2. Retrieve the video IDs.
3. Retrieve the channel IDs from the video IDs.
4. Retrieve the values of subscriberCount.
5. Put the values of subscriberCount to Spreadsheet.

When this flow is reflected in a Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. Before you use this script, please enable YouTube Data API v3 at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) And, please set the sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  
  // 1. Retrieve the video URLs from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  
  // 2. Retrieve the video IDs.
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => a.split("=").pop().trim());
  const check = values.slice();

  const limit = 50;
  const obj = [...Array(Math.ceil(values.length / limit))].reduce((obj, _) => {

    // 3. Retrieve the channel IDs from the video IDs.
    const res1 = YouTube.Videos.list(["snippet"], { id: values.splice(0, limit), maxResults: limit }).items.reduce((o, { id, snippet: { channelId } }) => (o[id] = channelId, o), {});

    // 4. Retrieve the values of subscriberCount.
    const res2 = YouTube.Channels.list(["statistics"], { id: Object.values(res1), maxResults: limit }).items.reduce((o, { id, statistics: { subscriberCount } }) => (o[id] = Number(subscriberCount), o), {});
    Object.entries(res1).forEach(([k, v]) => obj[k] = res2[v] ? res2[v] : "");

    return obj;
  }, {});

  // 5. Put the values of subscriberCount to Spreadsheet.
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(check.map(a => [obj[a] || ""]));
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of subscriberCount are put in the column "B" of the Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)
- [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)